# rxjs completes an observable immediately after error instead of continuing

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to stream a set of content through an observable and it stops after the first error.  It's simplist to think of this as an array of items as it behaves the same way.

1. I am creating an observable from an array of item
2. mapping each item to a URL
3. calling the URL as a request-promise
4. perform a catch() that returns an observable.empty() in the event of an error

Using RxJS 5:

```
rx.Observable.from(array)
  .map(self.createUrl)
  .flatMap(x => {
            var options = {
            uri: url,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            };
            return rx.Observable.fromPromise(request-promise(options));
        })
  .catch(() => {
    return rx.Observable.empty();})
  .subscribe( x => console.log('success:', x),
           e => console.log('error'),
           () => console.log('complete'));
```

When doing this sequence, the code stops after the first error is encountered.  I suspect the empty observable in #4 is terminating the observable but I'm not sure why.

My desired process is that all items in the array are processed regardless of errors - ultimately processing all successful items and resuming after each error.

Comment: The behavior makes sense. In the event of an error, the original observable completes and is replaced by an empty one. I think you were looking for [`onErrorResumeNext()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/onerrorresumenext.md). Use it, for example, in combination with `flatMap`

Comment: I tried that idea by wrapping the .from(Array) line with:
  rx.Observable.onErrorResumeNext(rx.Observable.from(array)),

That did nothing.

I'm not sure how I would wrap it off the flatMap  to the request? Or am I missing something inbetween?

Comment: sorry - pebkac.  wrap the observable *inside* the flatmap is what you're saying.  thank you.  It looks like I can't reply yet with a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put the `catch()` inside the `flatMap`:

```
rx.Observable.from(array)
  .map(self.createUrl)
  .flatMap(x => {
    var options = {
      uri: url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    return rx.Observable
      .fromPromise(request-promise(options))
      .catch(() => rx.Observable.empty());
  })
  .subscribe( x => console.log('success:', x),
           e => console.log('error'),
           () => console.log('complete'));
```

Now when then inner Observable emits an error it'll be caught immediately and won't propagate to the main stream through `.flatMap()`.